# Adding an Element to an array with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: arrays, c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying here to simply add one more element for `feld[N]` but I just can't figure out how. I was searching on the Internet for help, but nothing really helped me. It would be awesome if someone could give me a hint or two.

It could be that I'm not using `realloc()` correctly, but I'm not sure.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 50
#define N 20
    
struct student {
    unsigned int nummer;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
};
    
typedef struct student student_t;
    
int element_vergleich(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    student_t* sp1, * sp2;
    sp1 = (student_t*)p1;
    sp2 = (student_t*)p2;
    if (sp1->nummer < sp2->nummer)
        return -1;
    else if (sp1->nummer > sp2->nummer)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
    
void sortiere(student_t* f, int n)
{
    qsort(f, n, sizeof(student_t), element_vergleich);
}
    
int main(void)
{
    student_t feld[N] = { {59112, "Peter Lustig"}, {45181, "Fritz Fuchs"}, {38984, "Bibi Blocksberg"},
                            {87191, "Bernd Brot"}, {58731, "Katie Sommer"}, {75442, "Hein Klug"} };
    int n = 6;   // Anzahl benutzter Elemente im Feld

    printf("Das Feld wurde fuer %d Elemente deklariert. Davon werden %d Elemente benutzt.\n", N, n);
    
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {       
        printf("Element [%d]: Matrikelnummer: %d\tName Student: %s\n", i + 1, feld[i].nummer, feld[i].name);
    }

    printf("Geben Sie einen neuen Student_t Element ein.\n");
    printf("Geben Sie Matrikelnummer ein: ");
    scanf("%d", &feld->nummer);
    printf("Geben Sie Name des Studenten ein: ");
    scanf("%s", &feld->name);
    
    int* ptr;

    ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(student_t) * 7);

    feld[7].name = { "Linas Dagys" };
    feld[7].nummer) = 50846;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no specific question in your post, and there is no statement of what the program does wrong. In the future, when asking questions about code that is not working, include a [mre], including observed output from the program, and a statement of what is wrong and what you want the program to do instead.

Comment: For one thing, you can only `realloc` memory that was obtained from `malloc` or `calloc`: you cannot reallocate an array: its size is fixed. Another thing is this `int* ptr; ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(student_t) * 7);` is trying to reallocate an uninitialised value (let alone not having been dynamically allocated).

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong:

```
int* ptr;

ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(student_t) * 7);
```

`int* ptr;` defines `ptr` but does not give it any value. When `ptr` is passed to `realloc`, its value is indeterminate. You should pass `realloc` a value that is either a null pointer or a pointer to previous allocated memory (an address that was returned by a previous call to `malloc`, `realloc`, or a related routine).

Inside a function, `student_t feld[N] = …;` defines an array of automatic storage duration. This is not something intended to be changed by `realloc`. To work with an array whose size may change, you should allocate space for it with `malloc`, `realloc`, or a related routine, after which you may then use `realloc` to request that the allocation be changed.

You need to start not with a defined array but with a pointer whose value you assign by calling `malloc`, `realloc`, or a related routine. (You can use `realloc` to make an initial allocation by passing it a null pointer.) The type of the pointer should be a pointer to the type of elements you want in the array (`student_t`). `int *` is not the correct type for working with an array of `student_t` structures.

Then you can fill in the allocated memory with data, which you can copy from a defined and initialized array or by other means.

Once you have that array, then you can use `realloc` to change its size.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you have a typo:

```
feld[7].nummer) = 50846;
            ^^^^
```

In this declaration:

```
student_t feld[N] = { {59112, "Peter Lustig"}, {45181, "Fritz Fuchs"}, {38984, "Bibi Blocksberg"},
                          {87191, "Bernd Brot"}, {58731, "Katie Sommer"}, {75442, "Hein Klug"} };
```

You declared an array with exactly `20` elements due to the constant `N` defined like

```
#define N 20
```

Only `6` elements of the array were explicitly initialized. All other elements of the array are implicitly initialized by zeroes.

The indices of the initialized elements of the array are `[0,5]`.

So if you want to assign explicitly one more element of the array there is no need to "reallocate" the array. The array can not be reallocated. It has automatic storage duration instead of allocated storage duration.

This code snippet

```
int* ptr;

ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(student_t) * 7);
```

invokes undefined behavior because the pointer `ptr` used in the call of `realloc` is not initialized.  And secondly the code snippet in any case does not make sense because the pointer `ptr` is used nowhere except this code snippet and have nothing common with the declared array.

All you need is to assign values to the element of the array `feld` with the index `6`.

Pay attention to that arrays do not have the assignment operator. To store a string in a character array you need to copy it in the array.

So you should write:

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( feld[6].name, "Linas Dagys" );
feld[6].nummer) = 50846;
```

If you want to dynamically reallocate an array then initially you need to allocate it dynamically using function `malloc`.

Answer (score -2):

I know that realloc() funcion has some issues, so i suggest you to create another dedicated funcion, or a cycle, that uses malloc instead of realloc.
there are also some syntax errors like the bracket at the end "feld[7].nummer)".

Comment: Also I noticed that the reallocated variable is a pointer to nothing, so realloc is trying to increase the index of an empty box. But continue suggesting you to use malloc and calloc   if you can.